# Make derived class instance given base class instance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have this situation where

```
class Parent {
    int data;
    public Parent(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int childData;
    public Child(int data, int childData) {
        super(data);
        this.childData = childData;
    }
}
```

And on hand I have an instance of `Parent`.  I want to add the `childData` functionality to it.  I've recently been programming in Javascript where this is trivial, and I mentally ported over the design patterns without realizing this is nontrivial in Java.

Assuming I have full control over `Child` class code, what is the best practice to do this?  Can I do this without cloning?  Is it necessary to modify `Parent` class to get this to work?

Of course in the *worst* case (this sounds awful) there is this solution:

```
new Child(parent.data, childData);
```

Since `Parent`'s data are all public.

Specific problem (which I tend to forget to include on Java questions) is I have a `Config.testUser` method which returns user, and I would like to add one datum to it to make it an `InitialScanUser`, which is a `User` with an `initialScanAlgorithm` datum of type `InitialScanAlgorithm` added.  `Config.testUser` lives in a package which cannot depend on `InitialScanAlgorithm`.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this? Perhaps an example can illustrate what you need to use this for?

Answer (score 0):

Make `Parent` instances immutable and you can just delegate to an instance of `Parent`.

See [*Effective Java,* Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance.](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/classes-and-interfaces/ch04lev1sec4)

Comment: By "delegate" you mean doing a lot of `child.parent().method()`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not trivial. An instance class cannot be changed (although it can be *referenced* as a superclass reference, but the instance itself cannot change).

A more elegant way would be (if you use the construct a lot) to add a constructor that accepts a parent instance.

```
public Child(Parent parent, int childData) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: As @MattBall suggests, this is really pointing you towards composition vs inheritance.